# Kibana4 geo map Error - not showing the client_ip field

Tags: logstash, kibana-4

I am trying to get kibana-4 geo map to work with ELB logs

when i click the discover tab i can clearly see a field geoip.location with values of [lat, lon] 
but when i click the visualise tab -> Tile map -> new search -> Geo coordinates 
i get an error (not showing anywhere what is the error i've also checked the kibana logs - but nothing is there)

I checked inspect element - also nothing

I then select GeoHash, but the field is empty (when i click on it its blank with a check icon)

How can i see what is the error ?
How can get this map to work ?

my config is:

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "/logstash_data/logs/elb/**/*"
    exclude => "*.gz"
    type => "elb"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "log_sincedb"
  }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "elb" {
      grok {
        match => [
          "message", '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NGUSERNAME:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{POSINT:client_port} (%{IP:backend_ip}:%{POSINT:backend_port}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time} %{POSINT:elb_status_code} %{INT:backend_status_code} %{NUMBER:received_bytes} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes} \\?"%{WORD:method} https?://%{WORD:request_subdomain}.server.com:%{POSINT:request_port}%{URIPATH:request_path}(?:%{URIPARAM:query_string})? %{NOTSPACE}"'
        ]
      }

      date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
      }

      if [query_string] {
        kv {
          field_split => "&?"
          source => "query_string"
          prefix => "query_string_"
        }
        mutate {
          remove => [ "query_string" ]
        }
      }

      if [client_ip] {
        geoip {
         source => "client_ip"
         add_tag => [ "geoip" ]
        }
      }

      if [timestamp] {
        ruby { code => "event['log_timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')"}
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    cluster => "ElasticSearch"
    host => "elasticsearch.server.com"
    port => 9300
    protocol => "node"
    manage_template => true
    template => "/etc/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json"
    index => "elb-%{log_timestamp}"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

geo_ip index did not work in my case because my index names did not started with logstash-

if you want the custom index name to get the geo-ip, you must create a template for that index name

in the output for elasticsearch use it

```
elasticsearch {
      manage_template => true
      template => "/etc/logstash/templates/custom_template.json"
}
```

your template should look like this

```
{
  "template" : "index_name-*",
  "settings" : {
  "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
},
"mappings" : {
"_default_" : {
   "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
   "dynamic_templates" : [ {
     "message_field" : {
       "match" : "message",
       "match_mapping_type" : "string",
       "mapping" : {
         "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true
       }
     }
   }, {
     "string_fields" : {
       "match" : "*",
       "match_mapping_type" : "string",
       "mapping" : {
         "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
           "fields" : {
             "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
           }
       }
     }
   } ],
   "properties" : {
     "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
     "geoip"  : {
       "type" : "object",
         "dynamic": true,
         "properties" : {
           "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
         }
      }
   }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On our maps, we specify a field geoip.location which according to the documentation is automatically created by the geoip filter.

Can you see that field in discover? If not, can you try amending your geoip filter to

```
if [client_ip] {
  geoip {
     source => "client_ip"
     add_tag => [ "geoip" ]
     target => "geoip"
  }
}
```

and see if you can now see geoip.location in new entries?

The elasticsearch templates look for the "geoip" target when creating the associated geoip fields.

Once we have the geoip.location being created, we can create a new map with the following steps in Kibana 4.

1. Click on visualise
2. Choose '`Tile Map`' from the list of visualisation types
3. Select either new search or saved - we're using a saved search that filters out Apache entries, but as long as the data contains geoip.location you should be good
4. Select the '`geo coordinates`' bucket type - *you'll have an error flagged at this point*
5. In '`aggregation`' dropdown, select '`geohash`'
6. In '`field`' dropdown, select '`geoip.location`'

Comment: This is the discover tab clearly showing geoip.location, and some visualize warninig (docs values are not enabled on this field)

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s30/sh/8f1cf7fb-ecd4-403c-bf4d-b5aea5328e8a/2878f6f605e640ab2856c4107a86d45f)

Comment: @AmiMahloof, I've updated the original answer to show the steps to create a map once you've got the geoip.location field available in discover.

Comment: the issue is that i can't select something after the geohash

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s30/sh/8d01fb35-576f-4c86-87c1-01f701651421/159e15f33ea3dd2ac6cbca7c31b0ad89

Comment: I copied paste your config, deleted all indices, restarted logstash, waited for the logs to come, found geoip.location in the discover, followed your steps but the result is the same!, the field is blank

Comment: Have you refreshed the fields in Kibana - it will be able to see them but not necessarily work with them. Try going to the settings option in the Kibana dashboard, select your index name in the column that appears on the right and click the '`refresh`' symbol to reload the field definitions.

Comment: i tried your suggestion, and went back through the process of the visualize but the result is the same. there's has to be a log for that error somewhere

Comment: If you go to the settings, choose the appropriate index and find geoip.location in the list of fields, what is the field type?

Comment: geoip.location   number false                   true

this post suggest the index is formatted in the wrong way
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1906

any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74110/discussion-between-ami-mahloof-and-simonh).